# Flow - reading a union type property doesn't work when caching the common variable check

Tags: flowtype

In [this example](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/unions/#toc-disjoint-unions), Flow shows us a way to read properties depending on the type.

I have refactored it to look like this, and it works as expected:

```
type Success = { success: true, value: boolean };
type Failed  = { success: false, error: string };

type Response = Success | Failed;

function handleResponse(response: Response) {
  const value = response.success && response.value;
  const error = !response.success && response.error;
}
```

However, when the common property is a string, it works when doing a `===` check, but it doesn't if you cache the check into a variable:

```
type Success2 = { success: 'success', value: boolean };
type Failed2  = { success: 'not_success', error: string };

type Response2 = Success | Failed;

function handleResponse(response: Response2) {
  const isSuccess = response.success === 'success';

  // const value = response.success === 'success' && response.value;  // WORK

  const value = isSuccess && response.value;  // DOESN'T WORK
}
```

In other words, there must be a `===` check (literally) before reading the variable, can't have it in a variable.

Is this a known Flow limitation, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, this is expected behavior. The feature you are referring to here is [type refinement](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/). The implementation is based on the standard flow-control mechanisms of Javascript, meaning that saving the result of a test and using it later will discard the type information that Flow might otherwise be able to infer. All Flow knows in your non-working example is that `isSuccess` is a boolean, it has no idea that `true` there implies that `response.value` exists.

Comment: Understood. Is this something that is going to be implemented in the future, or is it that my design is wrong?

Comment: I don't think I can sat with 100% certainly, but I would not expect it to be something that would be implemented, since it would be incredibly hard once you account for the fact that random variables might be reassigned or that conditions might have been `true`  when originally evaluated, but that there is no guaranteed that the value would still accurately reflect the state by the time the boolean was actually checked.

Comment: Further, [Refinement Invalidations](https://flow.org/en/docs/lang/refinements/#toc-refinement-invalidations) explains that because of the risk of side effects from other statements, the type can only be inferred until the next statement.  Rather than saving the truthiness of the type test, save the result you want. e.g. `const value = response.success === 'success' ? response.value : undefined;`, or branch on the condition.